Integration with change of variable
$S(1)=S(0)e^{m+sZ}$ where Z is a random normal variable with standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. This means that $S(1)$ has lognormal distribution. The density function of $S(1)$ is equal to
$f(x)=\frac{1}{xs\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(ln\frac{x}{S(0)}-m)^2}{2s^2}}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x\le0$
We compute the expectation
$E(S(1))=\int_{0}^\infty xf(x)dx$
$E(S(1))=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(ln\frac{x}{S(0)}-m)^2}{2s^2}}dx$
Making the substitution $y=\frac{1}{s}(ln\frac{x}{S(0)}-m)$
we get $E(S(1))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty S(0)e^{sy+m}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy$
I am not clear on how we got the last line. First, how did the limits of integration went from $(0,\infty)$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$.
Second, where did $S(0)e^{sy+m}$ came from

When you take the definition of $S(1)$ at the very start of your post you can go directly to the last line without the detour through the density of the lognormal distribution. What you calculate is the expectation of a function of a normal variable. This should also answer your second question.

Besides using the way that Kurt suggest which is more direct and convenient to calculate using normal distribution, compared with lognormal distribution, in change of variable, as $x \to 0$, $y \to -\infty$; as $x \to +\infty$, $y \to +\infty$, this gives you the new integration limit when you change the variable. And consider the inverse transformation $x = S(0)e^{sy+m}$, we have
$dx = S(0)se^{sy+m}dy$ and thus you get the result.
